# What is the most important tradition in the Catholic Church?

Tags: catholicism, communion, tradition

I am doing a school project on Sacred Tradition and was wondering what Catholics view the most important Sacred Tradition to be. I was thinking that it would be Eucharist because it is the actual body and blood of our Lord. But then since tradition is equal to scripture in terms of authority, they all are equally important right?

Comment: How do you propose that this question be answered objectively?

Answer (score 1):

*What is the most important tradition in the Catholic Church?*

**The important Tradition is the Seven Sacraments** as it is the Church instituted means to attain salvation of souls.

> **Seven sacraments of the Catholic Church**
> The Catholic Church teaches that there are seven sacraments or rites through which God can communicate his grace to an individual. Catholic Christians believe that the sacraments are channels for God’s grace - every time they take part in a sacrament, they receive more grace.https://www.bbc.co.uk/bitesize/guides/zh4f3k7/revision/1

But in light of schism that happened post Vatican II, the most important tradition will be the very powerful words of Jesus to St.Peter and Apostles united to Peter.

*What is that Tradition based on the gospel coming from the very words of Jesus Himself?* The Apostles or College of Bishops united to the Pope is guided by the Holy Spirit the Spirit of Truth it cannot err.

> **The Promise of the Holy Spirit**
> …*12I still have much to tell you, but you cannot yet bear to hear it. 13However, when the Spirit of truth comes, He will guide you into all truth. For He will not speak on His own, but He will speak what He hears, and He will declare to you what is to come. 14He will glorify Me by taking from what is Mine and disclosing it to you*.-John16:12-14

And with regards to schism, the schismatic who are saying and spreading that a Pope is teaching errors as they continue to accuse Pope Francis of heresy. Based on Jesus powerful promised of protection, the Pope cannot teach errors or commit heresies when teaching *"faith & morals"*. Believing the Dubia Cardinals and Schismatic Bishops and their followers that a Pope can teach heresy will make Jesus a liar in Luke22:32.

> *"But I have prayed for you, Simon, that your faith will not fail. And when you have turned back, strengthen your brothers.”*-Luke22:32

More on this teachings on PASTOR AETERNUS.

> **THE PRIMACY OF THE SUCCESSOR OF PETER
> IN THE MYSTERY OF THE CHURCH** http://www.vatican.va/roman_curia/congregations/cfaith/documents/rc_con_cfaith_doc_19981031_primato-successore-pietro_en.html

Comment: Schism has nothing to do with this question, which is tradition.

Comment: @eques Yes, it is important in our times to uphold the Primacy of Peter and the infallibility of Living Church Magisterium because post Vat2 schismatic are distorting the Tradition of the Church.

Comment: The question is what is the most important tradition. Schism is not a tradition. You are just ranting about perceived "Schism"

Answer (score 0):

Tradition (*[traditio](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph?la=la&l=traditio)*) means "a passing on"; like the Olympic relay racers pass on the baton to the next runner, so does one generation of Catholics pass on the Deposit of Faith to the next.

Scripture itself is contained in Tradition, as it was the Church Herself who judged which books are to be part of the [canon of Holy Scripture](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/55496/1787).

In terms of the sacraments, baptism is the greatest because without it one cannot receive the other sacraments, including Holy Eucharist. However, Holy Eucharist comes in a close second. See [St. Thomas's ordering of the sacraments](https://isidore.co/forum/index.php?topic=131.msg356#msg356).

Fr. Chad Ripperger's books [*Topics on Tradition*](https://isidore.co/calibre#panel=book_details&book_id=4871) and [*The Binding Force of Tradition*](https://isidore.co/calibre#panel=book_details&book_id=4870) are also recommended.